# Slow change activity android

Tags: android, android-activity, andengine

I try to change from Activity to Activity from andengine and last loaded very slow.How can i insert between image with text "Tap to start" when andengine activity loading ends.I use this function to change.

```
startActivity(new Intent(ChangeLevelActivity.this, GameActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not switch activities - switch scenes.

Create different scenes for different "screens" in your game and switch between them - switching between scenes is fast and easy, much faster than activities.

Answer (score 1):

Jong is right, you should be switching scenes instead of activities.

If you look at the andengine source, there are some scene-types that may be useful to you. Look around "org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.*" You could make your own scene if you'd like, or you can extend a MenuScene so you can have more options.

If you just want a button that can start the game once it is loaded, check out the PauseExample in the andengine examples source. You could have the game be "paused" immediately after loading, and you can change the text to "Tap to Start", which will unpause the engine.